# How to use NgReduxTestingModule

Tags: angular, unit-testing, redux

I want to use MockNgRedux mocked store. I imported it to my test suite

```
import { NgReduxTestingModule, MockNgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store/testing';
```

Then I placed it in configureTestingModule imports.

In test case example object has been created and passed to the function I wanted to examined. As acting with the store is asynchronious action - I used fakeAsync zone, and called tick and detectChanges(). While I use subscribe() on Observable variable which should be updated by the store - application doesn't reach body of this method.

What do I wrong? Please help. It is my test:

```
it('should has specified version after calling changeVersion', fakeAsync(() => {

    let inputVersion: Version = new Version(); 
    inputVersion.id = 7;
    inputVersion.majorVersion = 1;
    inputVersion.minorVersion = 4;
    inputVersion.createdAt = new Date(2017, 6, 4);
    inputVersion.createdBy = "user1";

    component.changeVersion(inputVersion);

    console.log(MockNgRedux.mockInstance);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    console.log(MockNgRedux.mockInstance.getState()); //it's null

    let currentVersion: Version;

    component.selectedVersion$.subscribe((ver: Version) => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      currentVersion = ver;
    });

    expect(currentVersion.id).toBe(7);
 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your component property `selectedVersion$` is decorated with a `@select` decorator.

In your test, you need to tell the MockNgRedux instance what values you want to stub out in your test, e.g.

```
const selectedVersionStub = MockNgRedux.GetSelectedStub<IState, Version>(["path", "to", "version"]);
selectedVersionStub.next(new Version());
selectedVersionStub.complete();

component.selectedVersion$.toArray().subscribe(versions => {
    expect(versions.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Where `IState` is your state's root type, and the path to your version is the object traversal path to the item of your interest. In addition, I would recommend using `async` over `fakeAsync`... it will wait until all the async tasks have completed before evaluating your expectations. Note: selectedVersionStub is an `rxjs/Subject<Version>` type in this case, so you can pump values through with `next`, and close the observable with `complete` so that `toArray()` works.

Edit: you *can* use the `getInstance()` to spy on the `getState` method, but that will only work in the case where you are actually injecting `NgRedux` into your component and actually calling the `getState` method. Decorating with `@select` doesn't work in the same way.